# Bounties tab count doesn't update

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, tabs

The bounties tab [on my AskUbunutu profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/17739/root45?tab=bounties) shows one bounty badge.

[image]

This is correct, but it doesn't go away when I move to another tab.

[image]

Maybe this is by design and special for the bounties tab. But all the other tabs lose their badges after I click on them.

For example, if I get 10 reputation, it shows as a badge on the reputation tab. After I click on that tab, it goes away. This doesn't happen with the bounties tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), since it's indicating (to everyone who sees your profile, not just you) that you have an active bounty. All of the other counters are only displayed to you and reflect "new" things, which are no longer new after being viewed.